# cross database table references

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key

I try to create table `GroupArticle` in database `CmsGroup`, one column `ArticleId` references another table in another database? is this possible and correct syntax?

CmsArticle

```
CREATE DATABASE "CmsArticle"
WITH OWNER = db_admin
ENCODING = 'UTF8'
TABLESPACE = pg_default
LC_COLLATE = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
LC_CTYPE = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Article"(
"ArticleId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
"PublishDate" timestamp without time zone,
PRIMARY KEY ("ArticleId")
);
```

CmsGroup

```
CREATE DATABASE "CmsGroup"
WITH OWNER = db_admin
ENCODING = 'UTF8'
TABLESPACE = pg_default
LC_COLLATE = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
LC_CTYPE = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Group"(
"GroupId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
"PublishDate" timestamp without time zone,
PRIMARY KEY ("GroupId")
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "GroupArticle"(
"GroupArticleId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
"GroupId" integer NOT NULL,
"ArticleId" integer NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY ("GroupId") REFERENCES "Group" ("GroupId") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY ("ArticleId") REFERENCES "CmsArticle.Article" ("ArticleId") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY ("GroupArticleId")
);
```

Comment: If you need that, you probably want different schemas, not databases (and you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO.** You cannot create foreign key references on a different database.

Create the tables on the same database, if there is no specific reason to have them in separate databases.